# Why does app with embedded Adobe Reader Control work when published from VS 2013 but not VS 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, clickonce, manifest

My application uses the "Adobe PDF Reader" control to view PDF documents on a Windows Form. It is published as a ClickOnce app. If I publish it using Visual Studio 2013 it installs and runs fine. But if I publish it using Visual Studio 2017 (without making any changes to the solution), it will install but not run. It throws this error:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AxInterop.AcroPDFLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=963d585c671a3ae6' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So I went to "Publish/Application Files..." in Visual Studio to include the missing dll, only to find out I couldn't include it because it was not listed.

In VS 2017 the "Application Files" window looks like this:
[image]

But in VS 2013 the "Application Files" window looks like this:
[image]

Now in VS 2013 the MANIFEST file published in the ClickOnce folder contains this XML:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll" size="9216">
      <assemblyIdentity name="AxInterop.AcroPDFLib" version="1.0.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>Nyyy1D0D9ublZaujf9VDo73k2Ic=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" allowDelayedBinding="true" codebase="Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll" size="12800">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Interop.AcroPDFLib" version="1.0.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>ECgRqgvCeIc6FfkrboUllt0qScw=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

But the above XML is missing from the MANIFEST file when published with VS 2017.

Again, keep in mind this is exactly the same project and solution. I have changed nothing.

What do I need to do to get the VS 2017 published version to include the required dependency information? Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of days of investigation and trial and error, I have discovered a simple fix for my issue:

1. In VS 2017 do a "Build/Batch Build" for both the Debug and Release versions. NOTE: In doing so VS will put the necessary files "AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll" and "Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll" into the Bin\Release folder.
2. Now add a reference (using the Browse option) to add references to the "AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll" and "Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll" files in the Bin\Release folder.
3. In Solution Explorer/References right click on Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll and select Properties on the menu. Then in the Properties window change the "Embed Interop Types" to False.
4. Now go to Project Properties/Publish/Application Files and set the Publish Status to "Include" (not "Include (Auto)") for those two dlls.

I then published my application as a ClickOnce app using VS 2017 and everything worked without an exception. Issue resolved!

There is obviously a difference between the way Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2017 publish applications, as this "fix" wasn't necessary with VS 2013, but is with VS 2017.